# Configuring Crashlytics Without Using CocoaPods Not Getting Crash Reports

Tags: swift

For my app, I tried to configure the Firebase Crashlytics. For configuring I’m not using the pod file. Installed Firebase Without Using CocoaPods.  For that I followed the following link:
https://mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/

> Then I added GoogleService-Info.plist to the project from the Firebase account.

After that, I changed the DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT from DWARF to dwarf-with-dsym in Build options. Then I added the Run script in the Build phase.

Added the following script:
"${PROJECT_DIR}/ProjectName/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"

> For install build only selected
> Based on the dependency analysis is selected

Then in input files, I added the following:

> ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}

> $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

Changed the Scheme from debug to release.

I could not able to get the crash from crashlytics console. Is any issue is with the run scrips?
I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These configurations are not directly related to Crashlytics' crash report operation. These are used to send desymbollers to Firebase. So Firebase can desymbol your crash info and provide you a readable crash report. So, I am not sure that a failure in these configurations can cause your problem. As I know, if you have a failure in these steps; After your app crash, you need to see "Missing dsymbols" error on Firebase Crashlytics panel

If you cannot see your crash report, you need to check steps to integrate crashlytics properly. And maybe enable Firebase debug mode and check logs.

By the way, Crashlytics' first integration steps may be annoying. You may need to read and apply these steps carefully. Especially test crash step.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will do so

Comment: I tried the exact steps mentioned in the above link. I could not able to get the report in the crashlytics console.

Comment: That steps just about Firebase integration. Not its sub modules. You need to do this after that setup. Just replace the SPM step with your own way and carefully follow other steps.


https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

And also in your link, Crashliytics module isn't added in project. You need to ad it too.

Comment: "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/Project Name/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}" I added this on the run script. Now also crashlytics console showing "App detected and we're waiting for a crash!
Need help? Learn how to add a test crash"

Comment: Did you done step 3?

Comment: Also, since you don't use pods, you may need to change `${PODS_ROOT}`part with crashlytics' upload-symbols tool's location.

Comment: I can get crashes now. Thank you for your response